# how to Export Flash Player 10 compatible SWF from Flash CS3?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, flash-cs3, flashplayer-10

is there any way to export flash player 10 compatible swf from flash cs3 or for that i have to purchase Flash CS4??

is there any way to add new Flash Players in Publish Settings of Flash???

Thanx.

Comment: I think so... its not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to get CS3 to output a Flash 10 swf. (Trust me, I've tried).

Comment: Thanx for the answer. now another question :) , i recently read in an article that Flash CS5 is supporting maximum Flash player 10 and Adobe has released their Flash Player 10.1!!!!! i can't understand on which basis they are upgrading their Flash Player. Flash Player 10.1 is available but still we can't use its new Features because we can not Export swf to Flash player 10.1 from Flash CS5!!!! than who can use this new Flash Player 10.1????????

Comment: @Hardik CS5.5, the latest release, supports Flash 10.2. I would imagine that they would offer some way to publish for Flash 11 eventually, but that might be CS 6.

Comment: ok but again the current version is Flash Player 10.3 and CS5.5 supports Flash Player 10.2 as you said. then what is the use of Flash Player 10.3 now. as we can't export our swf to flash player 10.3 then for whom adobe makes Flash Player 10.3??? if users are downloading Flash player 10.3 but what is the use before their Authoring Tool. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!